# Cannot Add Service Reference after the service moved to TLS 1.2

Tags: tls1.2

While adding service reference for a web service on Windows server 2008 R2, I am facing following error:
 "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
This web service recently moved to TLS 1.2 and does not supports below versions of TLS.
Also I am able to Add Service Reference on my local machine using VS 2010 and .net framework 4.0